# Testing shared_preferences on flutter

Tags: testing, flutter, sharedpreferences

I'm writing a flutter application and I'm having this issue when writing the tests. This method is supposed to write data into TextFields and tap a button which saves this data in SharedPrefs:

```dart
testWidgets('Click on login saves the credentials',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {

    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    await tester.enterText(find.byKey(Key('phoneInput')), 'test');
    await tester.enterText(find.byKey(Key('passwordInput')), 'test');
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.lock));

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    expect(prefs.getString('phone'), 'test');
    expect(prefs.getString('password'), 'test');
  });
```

This test will fail getting the SharedPreferences instance with this error:

```
The following TimeoutException was thrown running a test:
TimeoutException after 0:00:03.500000: The test exceeded the timeout. It may have hung.
Consider using "addTime" to increase the timeout before expensive operations.
```

Update: Seems that the problem is not actually the timeout because even with 60 seconds the test is not capable of resolving the SharedPreferences instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needed to mock `getAll` from `shared_preferences` (ref: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences)

Here's the sample code:

```dart
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; // <-- needed for `MethodChannel`

void main() {

  setUpAll(() {
    const MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences')
        .setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
      if (methodCall.method == 'getAll') {
        return <String, dynamic>{}; // set initial values here if desired
      }
      return null;
    });
  });

  testWidgets('Click on login saves the credentials',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    await tester.enterText(find.byKey(Key('phoneInput')), 'test');
    await tester.enterText(find.byKey(Key('passwordInput')), 'test');
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.lock));

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    expect(prefs.getString('phone'), 'test');
    expect(prefs.getString('password'), 'test');
  });
}
```

---

<s>Original answer:</s>

```dart
testWidgets('Click on login saves the credentials',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
      final AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding = tester.binding;
      binding.addTime(const Duration(seconds: 10)); // or longer if needed
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    await tester.enterText(find.byKey(Key('phoneInput')), 'test');
    await tester.enterText(find.byKey(Key('passwordInput')), 'test');
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.lock));

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    expect(prefs.getString('phone'), 'test');
    expect(prefs.getString('password'), 'test');
  });
```

Comment: Seems that the problem is not actually the timeout because even with 60 seconds the test is not capable of resolving the SharedPreferences instance. Thanks for the Duration example anyway, it is really clarifying. I hope your PR gets merged soon.

Comment: I update the answer, you needed to mock `getAll` from `shared_preferences`

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be viable, as importing `'package:flutter/services.dart'` causes the `dart:ui` problem (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27826)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the provided mock `setMockInitialValues`

```dart
testWidgets('Click on login saves the credentials',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {

    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues(<String, dynamic>{
      'flutter.phone': '',
      'flutter.password': '',
    });

    await tester.enterText(find.byKey(Key('phoneInput')), 'test');
    await tester.enterText(find.byKey(Key('passwordInput')), 'test');
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.lock));

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    expect(prefs.getString('phone'), 'test');
    expect(prefs.getString('password'), 'test');
  });
```

Comment: In my problem what I wanted to test is if the preferences were modified with the right values when I clicked a button. If I initialize the preferences with this value the test would add no value at all since I'm fixing the result.

Comment: in this case, you attempt to set the initial value to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned at github you can do something like this at the beginning of your test:

```
tester.addTime(const Duration(seconds: 10));
```

Here is the link and full example :
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19175

```
testWidgets('MyWidget', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  final AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding = tester.binding;
  binding.addTime(const Duration(seconds: 10)); // or longer if needed
  await tester.pumpWidget(new MyWidget());
  await tester.tap(find.text('Save'));
  expect(find.text('Success'), findsOneWidget);
});
```

Comment: I can't find any method **addTime** on **WidgetTester**

Comment: Original author of that "example code" here, this code only works when the PR is merged

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by [TruongSinh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1326678/truongsinh) was not working for me. When I was trying to set values to SharedPreferences from the code, not tests, I was getting errors.

So here is an addition to that answer. You need to reimplement setters by yourself:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {

  setUpAll(() {
    final values = <String, dynamic>{};  // set initial values here if desired
    const MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences')
        .setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
      if (methodCall.method == 'getAll') {
        return values;
      } else if (methodCall.method.startsWith("set")) {
        values[methodCall.arguments["key"]] = methodCall.arguments["value"];
        return true;
      }
      return null;
    });
  });

  testWidgets('Test if your code works as designed', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    ...
  });

}
```